# Is it okay to bring skyscanner api response without session key?

Tags: api, skyscanner

When I tried to create session and polling session, it occurred 429 error and 304 response several times.(Skyscanner described trying over again when 304 is occurred, but it couldn't bring response many times.)

But when I use below url, it brings fast and clear response. Of course deep-link too.

> http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/UK/GBP/en-GB/EDI-sky/LHR-sky/2016-11-07/2016-11-14?apiKey={apiKey}

But there're no mention about this on document...
If someone has been used this, please give me some solution..

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? In my case even the URL you mentioned got me 429 error...

Comment: Um, No..I'm using the way with session key and it still caused 429 error.

Comment: Where did you get the url ? any documentations about it ?